# nginx-ingress-controller forever on "Scheduled for sync"

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I have an ingress for my application:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: myapi-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: mysite.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: "/posts"
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: myservice
            port:
              number: 80
```

When I run `kubectl describe ing myapi-ingress`, I can see that the ingress is stuck in sync state:

```
Events:
  Type    Reason  Age                From                      Message
  ----    ------  ----               ----                      -------
  Normal  Sync    26m (x2 over 27m)  nginx-ingress-controller  Scheduled for sync
```

PS. Before this happens, I tried to install another ingress for internal usage under another namespace and ingressclassname.

I'm getting 404 when I try to hit this endpoint. Nothing in the logs.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was the host name set on the Ingress

Comment: What hostname did you set in order to make it work?

Comment: Something like www.mycompany.com

Comment: I'm using my local docker desktop and have a host entry for `127.0.0.1 kubernetes.local` what would be the problem?

Comment: @RajaAnbazhagan In my case I need the entry - host: mysite.com

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when I created a new ingress with a secretName: of another existing ingress (which caused a conflict)

Once I changed the secretName:, of the new ingress to a unique name, and re-deployed the ingress, the cert was created.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to answer given by Rodrigo https://stackoverflow.com/a/75238886/2557517

In my case, i only had the entry for '*.mydomain.io' in the spec.tls.hosts section. I needed to add mydomain.io as well.

```
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: mydomain-ingress
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
      - '*.mydomain.io'
      - mydomain.io   # this is required
      secretName: secret-mydomain-20240305
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: '*.mydomain.io'
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: mydomain-frontend
                port:
                  number: 3001
    - host: mydomain.io
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: mydomain-frontend
                port:
                  number: 3001
```